# ___ of the students should do his own work

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, exam-questions

> **Q:** ___ of the students should do his own work.
>   a) everyone
>   b) all
>   c) each
>   d) every

I think the answer is **each** (c) because we use *each* to talk about individual members of the group as separate items.

Am I missing something? Are both the answer and the reason correct?

Comment: I think the answer is (c), also. Why do you think you're missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**everyone** doesn't fit because it's a noun in itself, you can't say **everyone of*.

**all** doesn't fit because the latter part is singular (*his*, not *their* own work), while *all of...* is a plural noun phrase.

**every** doesn't link with "of" either, it modifies a noun directly (*every student should...*)

So the only remaining answer is indeed (c). Another acceptable one would be "every one" (note the space!), as in:

> Every one of the students should do his own work.